# Sql injectability of my php script

Tags: php, mysql, security, validation

Normally I do this for all my user inputs both strings and numerical inputs:

```
$matric_no = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['matric_no']);
```

And I use the parameter on the LHS to get the required value either to work on or post into mysql. Is this practice enough security wise? Is it a good practice?

Thanks for your help..

Comment: Can you show the query you're using this in?

Comment: @Pekka Well, let's say i use it for an INSERT/UPDATE statement. Is this practice a good one?

Comment: the practice itself is not only good but even *necessary* :) But whether it's enough depends on your query. Show a real-life query

Comment: As for numerical inputs, you need to check for them being, actually, numerical; mysql_real_escape_string escapes...strings

Comment: For integer only input, using `intval()` is better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as *all* of your variables being inserted into the query *are enclosed in quotes* and escaped using `mysql_real_escape_string()`, you should be okay.

If possible, I recommend using the [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension instead of the obsolete Mysql extension.  If you do, then you can make use of parameter binding, and be 100% sure that your queries are safe from injection (as long as you bind *all* parameters, that is).

Comment: Depending on the character sets in use in your PHP and MySQL, it can still be possible to inject SQL into quote-enclosed mysql_real_escaped queries. As suggested, just avoid the myriad of problems with string-munging functions and use bound parameters instead.

Comment: how can i use it with htmlentities and stripslash functions... Probably make it into a function. Please i dont know.